# Handling two threads with high frequency reads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, serial-port, real-time

I'm writing a simple app that constantly reads some data from serial port over bluetooth and then draws that data on 2 charts. I came up with an idea of buffering that data to byte buffer and then reading it from some other part of the code. The problem is that I have to read that data quite frequently (reading only 5 bytes at once) and I have some issues with synchronization of the threads. The serial port reading part is not allowing the printing thread to read anything most of the time. Sometimes it gets through and prints some data. These 2 are the only threads that use `buffer` as the locking object.

I think I might've missunderstood some basic synchronization principles, but I'm starting to run out of ideas how can I solve this issue.

Reading from serial port part:

```
public void startReading() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            resetBuffer();
            read = true;
            try {
                serialPort.purgePort(SerialPort.PURGE_RXCLEAR);
                byte[] buf = new byte[5];
                int bytes;

                while (read) {
                    synchronized (buffer) {
                        try {
                            bytes = inputStream.blockingRead(buf);
                            System.out.println(buf);

                            System.arraycopy(buf, 0, buffer, bufferPos, bytes);
                            bufferPos += buf.length;

                            buffer.notifyAll();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (SerialPortException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();

}
```

Printing data part (in loop):

```
 synchronized (buffer) {
        while (serialPortConnection.getBufferLength() < 5) {
            try {
                buffer.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    readBytesToStringBuffer();
    printLineIfAvailable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (read) {
  synchronized (buffer) {
    try {
       bytes = inputStream.blockingRead(buf);
```

Your problem is not in reading often; it is in *blocking*. You acquire the monitor on `buffer` and then enter a blocking I/O call. You spend precious little time outside of that call, thus outside of the `synchronized` block.

#### Advice:

First read from port outside of `synchronized`, then acquire the monitor to transfer the data to a shared structure.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks a lot. I don't get it though why wouldn't it release the monitor for the other thread when reading from port inside a `synchronized` block.

Comment: Monitor release happens only under well-defined conditions, such as invoking `wait` on the object. No such thing goes on in the blocking method.

Comment: That explains everything, `blockedRead` was keeping the monitor all the time and it was released only for a very short period of time after each `while` iteration.